# vtkMy python wrapping

Tags: c++, python, cmake, word-wrap, vtk

[VTK](http://www.vtk.org/) offers the possibility to extend the library with C++ classes so that they can be used in Python (or in any language supported). As far as I know, there are two way to do that, using the examples folders vtkLocal or vtkMy provided with the library (Examples/Build/).

I would like to use this functionnality, but I don't understand the installation process (vtk 5.8 on Debian). I follow the README instruction on vtkMy, it compiles and generetate 3 files : vtk*.so vtk*Python.so and vtk*PythonD.so.
What I am suppose to do next ? I've tried appending those file's path to `$PATH`, `$PYTHONPATH` or `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as suggested, but I've never been able to `import` anything into Python.

Any insight or even some instructions on how to compile/import/use the dummy classes provided in vtkMy would be a tremendous help.

Comment: Also stuck on this, did you find an answer?